# If Then Modelbuilder, Project error

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have a model where I want to check the projection. If it is GCS_WGS_1984, I want it to go one path, and if it isn't, I want it to go another path.

I created a "Check Coordinates of Input" script to output two Boolean values of True or False. The script is:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

Footprints = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

desc = arcpy.Describe(Footprints)
type = desc.spatialReference

try:
    if type.name == "GCS_WGS_1984":
        arcpy.SetParameterAsText(1, "True")
        arcpy.SetParameterAsText(2, "False")

     else:
        arcpy.SetParameterAsText(1, "False")
        arcpy.SetParameterAsText(2, "True")
except Exception as e:
    AddPrintMessage(e[0], 2)
```

[image]

When the input isn't in GCS_WGS_1984, the model is able to run okay. I get the True.kmz file but in the messages I also get "The process did not execute because the precondition is false" and "All the inputs are not current". When the input file is in GCS_WGS_1984 however, I get and error message from the Project function of "invalid geographic transformation" and it stops there.

How do I get it so that if the coordinates are true, the goes along the upper path, and if it's false, to go along the lower path?

I was reading something on ArcGIS's online resource about a Run Model Parameter http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w0000007r000000 being checked and was wondering if that would make a different? Still though, I don't know how to access that.

And this is for later if it all works out: If I'm running this in a tool dialog box, the options for the true and false kmz will be required, even if only one is going to be created?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options in model builder:

1. Use [Calculate Value](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004000000004000000) to test a condition and output a boolean
2. Write a custom script tool to test the condition.  There is a [good
   sample script](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w00000022000000) on the help page which checks for a certain
   projection and outputs a boolean.

**More information here:**

[Using if-then-else logic in ModelBuilder](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w00000022000000)